# Measure usage of a custom node js app deployed on azure

Tags: node.js, azure

I have hosted a node.js app using an azure VM connected to a cloud service. Now i am trying to figure out how many sessions have hit that endpoint and their usage around it like, server response time, latency, memory usage, disk usage, unique users etc. Is there a way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VMs, you need to implement logging mostly by yourself.

Azure, using the Portal, allows you to view metrics for the VM, like CPU and memory usage. However, to get application-level metrics, such as response times, number of requests, etc, you need to design your own solution.

- If your Node.js application communicates with the Internet through a reverse proxy (e.g. Nginx, IIS, etc), then you could fetch those metrics from your web server's logs
- Otherwise, you'll have to implement logging inside your JS code. The correct way depends on the framework you're using (if any): Express, Koa, Hopi, etc.

On the other hand, were you using PaaS (Azure Web Apps), you'd get most of these metrics automatically.